# Putting into the jobExecutionContext - UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have the following step defined in my spring batch project. I've simplified the code for brevity.

```
@Bean
@JobScope
public JdbcCursorItemReader<MasterList> queryStagingDbReader(
        @Value("#{jobExecutionContext['" + ExecutionContextConstants.JOB_EXPORT_STAGING_PROMOTION_START_DATE_END_DATE_GROUPINGS +"']}")
        List<PromotionStartDateEndDateGrouping> promotionStartDateEndDateGroupings,
        @Value("#{jobExecutionContext}")Map<String, Object> jobExecutionContext) {  

    jobExecutionContext.put(ExecutionContextConstants.JOB_EXPORT_STAGING_WORKING_PROMOTION_START_DATE_END_DATE, "Hello");

}
```

My problem is that when I try to add to the jobExecutionContext as per the put statment above I get ...

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.put(Collections.java:1457) ~
```

If this does not work how can I add to the jobExecutionContext?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you receiving there is not the actual `ExecutionContext`.  It's a `Map` with the values within the `ExecutionContext`.  To obtain the actual `ExecutionContext`, you'd need to grab it from the `JobExecution` itself.  That being said, in most cases, `StepScope` is more appropriate or the native singleton.